# Qualcomm ar9485

Tags: wireless

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Samsung NP270E4E and my wireless adapter is hard blocked:

[image: screenshot of terminal showing output of rfkill list all, revealing that phy0 is not soft blocked but is hard blocked, and hci0 is neither soft blocked nor hard blocked]

So I don't know what to do.

Comment: Does Fn+F12 unblock the wireless? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text; just copy/paste the text into your question and mark it as a code "*{}*" block

Comment: @chili555 no, it doesn't unblock the wireless

Comment: @guiverc that's what it says:
david@laptop-kehila:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Please add additional information to your question; you can edit your own questions and it allows formatting which makes it easier to read.

Comment: @guiverc, What extra information do you need? Let me know for explain myself better

Comment: Depending on device used, headings don't always display so question body needs to include all information (iie. repeating any info in heading), plus you have a picture link but no description detail (comments likewise do not always show). Why additional information needs to be in the text of the question).  Your last comment to me was *unreadable unformatted* babble, and you should make it easy when seeking help from people.  Even if you don't know the site's formatting, in question/answers we can help you, but comments can only be deleted.

Comment: @guiverc, I understand, the apologies of the case, the truth is that I hardly know how to write English, but I don't know what else to describe you, well ... my laptop is a Samsung NP270E4E, 4GB RAM, Intel Celeron 1.10GHz, AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter, I don't know what else you need? I don't know if this is enough? If you need anything else please let me know.